# Group by two columns, sort by third column in descending order pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

I have a df called "df_filled_weeks" with columns "retailer_id", "store_id", "chain", "week_id"  (and others).

I am trying to group my data first by retailer_id then store_id and then sort by descending week_id within each group.

I tried:

```
df_filled_weeks.groupby(['retailer_id', 'spins_store_id']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["week_id"], ascending = False))
```

but this does not seem to work. Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sort first then group

Comment: So switch the places of the  groupby and apply functions?

Comment: You need to reset your index otherwise alignment is going to force everything back together where it was. or ignore_index.

Comment: It kind of seems like you could do `df_filled_weeks.sort_values(['retailer_id', 'spins_store_id', 'week_id'], ascending=(True, True, False))`?

Comment: Where should the reset_index / ignore_index be applied? At the end of the line?

Comment: `x.sort_values(["week_id"], ascending = False).reset_index(drop=True)` or `x.sort_values(["week_id"], ascending = False, ignore_index=True)`